# Postgresql via Docker - postgres is not running automatically

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

The main problem is that i cannot run postgresql even on vm with the error:

```
root@a2c8a58d4e0e:/# psql -h localhost -U psqluser -W
Password for user psqluser:
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

For that purpose i run this commands inside VM:

```
pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

And then it works properly on VM. But that's manually.

I configured everything by official docker repo docs.

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  postgresql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgresql
    container_name: Postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'psqldb'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'psqluser'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'temp123'
    volumes:
    - /home/VOLUMES/DB/Postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
```

I did inheritance from original repo as i want to run postgresql service automatically. Otherwise it's not running.

postgresql file:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.11
RUN pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

It does not run Postgres as well. Only manually inside VM.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Within docker compose, ports aren't exposed on the host by default. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

`ports` is virtual within the docker compose network. If you want to expose them to the host machine, you can use the `expose` option instead of `ports`.

Alternatively, you can also run `docker-compose run` with the `--service-ports` flag which will automatically expose the ports to the host when running.

`docker-compose run --service-ports postgresql` ([see doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/))

Comment: tried without ports and still getting ```root@85e21cca0d93:/# psql -h localhost -U psqluser -W
Password for user psqluser:
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```

Comment: From the error message: "Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)"? Is it? It is with docker-for-mac but for different setup it can be different. Then about the `ports` option; you must not remove it. Either **replace** it with `expose` or run with `--service-ports` flag.